# Facebook Open Graph Debugger returns blank page

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

The Facebook Open Graph Debugger has been a faithful friend for a very long time. I use it frequently and with succes.

However, when I try to debug certain pages from the website jannekestielstra.nl, the query results in a completely blank page. No header, no footer, no content. Completely blank.

For instance, debugging http://jannekestielstra.nl/daisy-goddijn/ results in a blank page:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjannekestielstra.nl%2Fdaisy-goddijn%2F

Has anyone seen this before? And does anyone know what causes this?

Thanks in advance.

Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ instead, it often works better in my experience. (I don’t know why, the underlying technology should be the same.)

---

You can also file a bug report, if you like - if the scraper/sharing debugger has a problem with your URL, then it at least should tell you what that problem is, and not “die” with a blank page. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Curl Timeout: The request to scrape the URL timed out.